# How to set two A record and two Mx record for a domain

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a bind dns server 9.3.4-P1 in centos5.3.
What i need is to set two A record and 2 Mx record for a single domain,  so that if some thing happen to the first server after a particular interval the dns response change to the second server IP.

Comment: So what's the problem you're having with actually going ahead and doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many MX and A records as you like for a domain.  Simply specify them.  Here is an example in case that is unclear:

```
example IN A 192.0.2.40
example IN A 192.0.2.41
example IN MX 10 mx1.example.net.
example IN MX 20 mx2.example.net.
```

If you do this, you will have created a round robin record for `IN A example`.  You can also specify the round-robin DNS record as the first-priority MX for the DNS name, but if you want, you can create separate A records for each server so that you can specify multiple MX records with different priorities (to designate one as the primary MX and the other as the backup).

Keep in mind that this isn't enough to provide failover for your services.  In the case of round-robin A records, the client will typically get all the records in a reply, but will usually ignore all but the first, so if one of the servers is down there will be intermittent problems.  If it's reliability you are needing, you should consider setting up a load balancer that can heartbeat the hosts and only direct requests to ones that are up.

SMTP works a little differently in this regard; mailservers will be tried in order of priority until a working one is found.  However, you may still choose to use a load balancer with heartbeating in this case too.

Comment: How the dns respond based on the server availabillity?

Did dns check the primary server for availabilly and it will respond ?? And how much time the dns wait for the primary server response. Is there any way I can set it out the time for switching form primary to secondary when primary is not available

Comment: DNS is not a load balancer or a mechanism for providing failover; it is a directory.  I'll amend my answer in a moment to clarify what this means.